# How to prove that a sequence of complex numbers converges absolutely for $\frac{\pi}{4} < \lvert\arg z\rvert < \frac{3\pi}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let we have a convergent series
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}z_{k} \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\pi}{4} < \lvert\arg z_k\rvert < \frac{3\pi}{4}, \quad k \geq 0
$$

How to prove that in this case the series converges absolutely?

I had an idea to use convergence of $\sum_k \operatorname{Re}(z_{k})$ and ratio $\left|\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)}{\operatorname{Re}(z)} \right|< \tan(\arg(z))$ to show that it follows $|z_k| < \lvert\operatorname{Im}(z_{k})\rvert + \lvert\operatorname{Re}(z_{k})\rvert$, but I don't understand how can I go to $\sum_k \operatorname{Re}(z_{k})$ and then to absolute convergence?

Comment: Using $|z_k | \le |Re(z_k )|+|Im(z_k )| \le 2Im(z_k )$ solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to make trasition from $\sum z_{k}$ to your inequality

Comment: By a rotation of $45$ degrees (which preserves hypothesis and conclusion) you can reduce to the case of the argument from $0$ to $\pi/2$ where both the real and imaginary part are non negative so the hypothesis implies the series of those converges hence absolutely and then the result is clear